# How can I create "QuizUp" similar graphics in ios?

Tags: ios, opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone, uikit, quartz-2d

An application in AppStore's name "Quizup" probably know. 
(https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/quizup-biggest-trivia-game/id718421443)

Kind of like game contest application. Competing with other people and if you know you will give points according to questions, you can skip levels etc. ..
I'm developing a game, like this game, but with a different concept, I am working on an educational game, but like the above images and animations in published application looks very soft and pleasant.
I'm wondering, exactly what tools using for developing this app?

Quartz 2d, UIKit, OpenGL-ES or game library(cocos2d etc.)?

What do you think I should use?

Thanks for your help.

Sorry poor english (I'm not native speaker)

Comment: Nothing special there just use UIKit and you might need the little core graphics

Comment: The app was made using Cocos2d http://stackoverflow.com/a/20693614/367006

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement all its UI/animations using UIKit & Quartz.