# How to make a menu looking like the one in QuizUp

Tags: ios

I gave a look on QuizUp and I would like to make a similar menu on my iphone application.

I don't understand how they made the menu. It looks like a table view controller, but a new menu appears under the cell when the user tap on it.

Can someone give me some clues. Is it possible to do that with the native iOS SDK ? How ?

Comment: I haven't seen that app, but it's probably done by using an expandable table view cell. Try searching on that here on SO, there are plenty of examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[According to the developer of Quiz Up,](http://www.reddit.com/r/iOSProgramming/comments/1scrwl/quizup_animations/) the app was made using Cocos2D.

That being said, it is also possible to do it using a `UITableView`. Theres just a couple things you would need to do. The first is get `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` to return a different height for the row(s) you want to be expanded. For example, if you only want one row expanded you could use the following.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ([[tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] isEqual:indexPath]) {
        return 100.0f;
    }
    return 44.0f;
}
```

Then what you need to do is call `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates` on your tableview whenever you want the height to update.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView beginUpdates];
    [tableView endUpdates];
}
```

After that, you just need to layout your cell so that when it's expanded, it shows the additional view and when its collapsed it should hide that view.